# Funny message when changing ownership of top directory in a mounted file system

Tags: permissions, mount

For unknown reason, the ownership of this directory changed.  This is a mount point: VM-data is /dev/sda3 which is a btrfs file system.

When I changed it back, I got an error,

```
chown: changing ownership of 'VM-data': No space left on device
```

but it seems to have worked.

```
linux-7gt2:/srv # ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Sep 25  2014 ftp
drwxr-x--- 1 tftp tftp   0 Apr 28 07:04 tftpboot
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 176 Oct 26  2014 VM-data
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36 Oct 26  2014 www
linux-7gt2:/srv # chown john:users VM-data
chown: changing ownership of ‘VM-data’: No space left on device
linux-7gt2:/srv # ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Sep 25  2014 ftp
drwxr-x--- 1 tftp tftp    0 Apr 28 07:04 tftpboot
drwxr-xr-x 1 john users 176 Oct 26  2014 VM-data
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   36 Oct 26  2014 www
linux-7gt2:/srv #
```

There is 133GB free on that device, according to fd.
"no space" is also the kind of misleading errors I got from a program that was using files in that directory, because it could not write to it.  So I wonder if that is the real error or not?

This is the top of a mounted tree, so I wonder if there is something special about how to set ownership and permissions for the file system as a whole that I need to worry about.

---

### update

It seems to be a glitch in btrfs made it go into read-only mode.  Marking it root is probably also part of the defensive lock-down when it detects some error.

I don't know how to check to see if a mount is `ro` or `rw`. I only know what I asked of it, and that differs.

I never saw any indication of errors either.  On a desktop OS, can something be turned on to alert the user?

Comment: Is your device mounted with read / write perms ?

Comment: What do `df` and `df -i` show for `/srv/VM-data`? Also, can you `chown` on say a subdirectory of that directory (i.e. is the error only on the top-level dir, or also on subdirs)?

Comment: @thrig I didn't try chown on subdirs, but `touch` to try writing a file: still gave "disk full" even with permission fixed.  I *think* it remounted ro on its own accord, but don't know how to check that directly.

Comment: What I did do is try another partition that was mounted with the same text in fstab. So I know `default,discard` normally works ok and is rw (the meaning of default didn't change from yesterday).